# If two consecutive cells are blank then second cell equals value

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to get this much working but not able to get it to start from Range("B12:B500").

```
Sub findTwoEmptyCells()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim firstEmptyCell As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
    Set firstEmptyCell = Cells(i, 1)
    Exit For
End If
Next i

End If

firstEmptyCell.Value = "x"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not `If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" And Cells(i+1, 1).Value = ""`?

Comment: Please, try `For i = 12 To lastRow` and then use `If Cells(i, 2).Value = "" And ...`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replies. None of the suggestions worked.

Comment: I Combined both your suggestions and got the result i was looking for. Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dominique & @FaneDuru, i was able to get the result as per the below by combining both their ideas :

```
Sub findTwoEmptyCells()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim firstEmptyCell As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 12 To lastRow
If Cells(i, 2).Value = "" And Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "" Then
    Set firstEmptyCell = Cells(i, 1)
    Exit For
End If
Next i


If firstEmptyCell Is Nothing Then 
MsgBox ("There are no two empty cells in a row")
Exit Sub
End If

firstEmptyCell.Value = "x"

End Sub
```