# Excel vba if three or more consecutive cells are blank then place value on another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking for a solution to get the result as in the screenshot. If theres at least 3 blanks or more then change second cell from first blank on first column to "x" :

```
Sub findThreeEmptyCells()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim firstEmptyCell As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 10 To lastRow
If Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "" And Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = "" Then
    Set firstEmptyCell = Cells(i + 2, 1)
    Exit For
End If
Next i

If firstEmptyCell Is Nothing Then 
MsgBox ("There are no two empty cells in a row")
Exit Sub
End If

firstEmptyCell.Value = "x"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43688009/4961700

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If two consecutive cells are blank then second cell equals value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009856/if-two-consecutive-cells-are-blank-then-second-cell-equals-value)

Comment: Im looking for something based on the 5th Column and minimum 3 consecutive blank cells

Comment: Then edit what you have so far. Or show how you have edited it to achieve what you now want, then people may help sort any errors.

Comment: Nevermind i found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub findThreeEmptyCells()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim firstEmptyCell As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row ' Assuming your column A has the most data or is the row you want to check.

For i = 10 To lastRow
If Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = "" And Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = "" And Cells(i + 3, 5).Value = "" Then
    Set firstEmptyCell = Cells(i + 2, 1)
    Exit For
End If
Next i

If firstEmptyCell Is Nothing Then 
MsgBox ("There are no two empty cells in a row")
Exit Sub
End If

firstEmptyCell.Value = "x"

End Sub
```